Run angular server with ssl results in node:events:496 throw er;
I am trying to host local angular server with self-signed certificate.
Certificate and key are generated using openSSL. Running openSSL server with them works as expected, Running empty node.js server with them works as well. However, when trying to run an angular project I get next results.
To use SSL I changed angular.json:
"options": {
            "ssl": true,
            "sslKey": "path/to/ssl/key.key",
            "sslCert": "path/to/ssl/cert.crt"
          },

Server starts as expected and I recieve the ususal ng serve info in console:
Browser bundles
Initial chunk files  | Names            |  Raw size
polyfills.js         | polyfills        |  90.20 kB |
main.js              | main             |  18.07 kB |
styles.css           | styles           |   7.88 kB |

                     | Initial total    | 116.15 kB


Server bundles
Initial chunk files  | Names            |  Raw size
polyfills.server.mjs | polyfills.server | 572.91 kB |
main.server.mjs      | main.server      |  19.47 kB |
server.mjs           | server           |   1.93 kB |

Application bundle generation complete. [3.328 seconds]

Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
NOTE: Raw file sizes do not reflect development server per-request transformations.
  ➜  Local:   https://localhost:4200/
  ➜  press h + enter to show help


However, when trying to access  https://localhost:4200/, the server is closed and I recieve the next error:
node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readable')
    at IncomingMessage._read (node:_http_incoming:214:19)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:737:12)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:1255:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on IncomingMessage instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at errorOrDestroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:238:7)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:739:7)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:1255:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v20.11.1


I put next code into server.ts to recieve error info:
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    console.error('Uncaught Exception:', err);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
});

and received next message when the server was closed:
Uncaught Exception: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readable')
    at IncomingMessage._read (node:_http_incoming:214:19)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:737:12)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:1255:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Uncaught Exception: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'content-security-policy')
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:661:45)
    at Immediate.write (file:///D:/%D0%B4%D0%B7/7%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%84%D0%B4%D1%88%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%84%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8
9%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B6%D1%89%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B6%D1%89%D1%84%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80/%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B7/project/APPZ_front
/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CB_7IfJ-.js:41049:9)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:480:21)

The error is replicated on a fresh angular project, with no changes applied to it. I could not find any similar errors online.
Versions installed:
$ ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 19.0.1
Node: 20.11.1
Package Manager: npm 10.8.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 19.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1900.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   19.0.1
@angular-devkit/core            19.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      19.0.1
@angular/cli                    19.0.1
@angular/ssr                    19.0.1
@schematics/angular             19.0.1
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.6.3
zone.js                         0.15.0

